# How to backup Ubuntu in a remote Ubuntu system?

Tags: backup, remote, rsync

I am having a Ubuntu desktop. I need to backup the contents of my Ubuntu system in another Ubuntu system that is connected over a local area network. How can I schedule automatic backup to that remote location. Is there any software to achieve backup in a remote computer ?. I have installed Grsync but I not sure how to use is to store backup in a remote host. Kindly explain me

Comment: I am very new to Ubuntu..so please explain me completely including steps and commands

Comment: If you know exactly what data (home directory,  settings,  log files,  etc.?) you need backed up,  it will make it easier to supply a specific answer.

Comment: @belacqua i need to backup a particular directory under the file system ( / ) and save the backup in another computer connected via local network

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/a/31530/63898 as well as the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

`deja-dup` backup tool works great. You can backup/restore from a remote host using sftp, windows share, samba share and so.

Comment: could you please explain the steps